# Dialog won't 're-show' after pressuing home key and relaunching app

Tags: android, view, dialog, splash-screen

I have a 'loading' dialog which is basically a very simple splash-screen that just display a 'loading' graphic while all the resources for my (Android) app loads.

Once it's all done, the dialog is dismissed.  Everything works great.  Apart from one thing....

If the user presses the 'home' key while the 'loading' dialog is displayed and then returns to the app *before* everything is loaded, all I get is a blank screen.  It still works though.... ie, eventually, the blank screen is replaced by my app.

So, why doesn't my dialog 're-display'?  I've confirmed that I'm returning to my app before the dialog is dismissed, so I really don't understand it.  At all other points in my game it returns with the screen *exactly* as it was if paused and immediately relaunched.

I'm creating my dialog like so this code is in **onCreate()**:

```
        load_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        load_dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

I then show it like so (also in **onCreate()**)

```
        //Set and display splash screen view
        load_dialog.setContentView(splash);
        load_dialog.show();
```

Once everything has loaded, in my GLRenderer classes' **onSurfaceCreated()** method, I simply dismiss it...

```
         load_dialog.dismiss;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behaviour as your activity is paused when you hit home.

Make your loading_dialog global. Then inside of onResume() call:

```
if (load_dialog != null && !load_dialog.isShowing())
    load_dialog.show();
```

Also remember that your activity will be re-created even if while loading you rotate the screen. So you need to watch for that too.

Comment: Hi @user3249477 - when you say 'global' as you referring to 'static'?

Comment: I'm referring to an instance variable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @user3249477, unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  I had neglected to pause my main (openGL) view in onPause (**myView.onPause()**) - with this code in place, I don't need to have a load_dialog.show(); in my onResume.  It's there already when I resume anyway :-)